# Bar plot for two column of a data frame, side by side

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

For the following data, which describes the occurrence of cancer types in the train set and test set of some model:

```
structure(list(cancer_type = c("Breast", "colorectal", "Melanoma", 
"Lung Cancer", "Renal Cell Carcinoma", "Sarcoma", "Thymic Carcinoma", 
"Bladder Cancer"), train_set = c(11, 4, 321, 28, 527, 5, 5, 242
), test_set = c(0, 2, 108, 13, 174, 0, 5, 77)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I need a bar plot to plot this side by side, something like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried? Where are you  having issues precisely?

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `ggplot2`

One approach would be to convert data to long format and then plot.

```
df_long <- df %>% mutate(n = train_set  + test_set) %>%
  arrange(n) %>%
  mutate(cancer_type = factor(cancer_type, cancer_type)) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  pivot_longer(-cancer_type, names_to = "value", values_to = "count")
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(
  fill = value,
  y = count,
  x = cancer_type,
  label = count
)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
    angle = 90,
    vjust = 0.5,
    hjust = 1
  )) + xlab("Cancer type") + ylab("Number of cases") +
  geom_text(size = 3,
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            vjust = -0.25)
```

Output:

[image]